# What is the relationship between string diagrams for monoidal categories, and string diagrams for natural transformations?

Tags: category-theory

String diagrams are used in two rather different contexts (that I know of).

Firstly, they are used for monoidal categories, where they typically look something like circuit diagrams and the important things are the boxes and the wires that connect them, and equations look like this:
[image]

Secondly, they are used for 2-categories (and for the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ in particular). Here the wires are functors, the boxes are natural transformations, and in addition the areas in between the wires are important, since they represent categories. An example of an equation is (from [Marsden, 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7220)):
[image]

There are some small differences between these two types of notation, but in general they are very similar. In both cases the idea is that you can manipulate the diagrams according to rules that depend on exactly which categories you're dealing with, but which generally correspond to topologically intuitive operations like bending wires around each other, sliding boxes along the wires, and so on.

In my own informal notes, I also use string diagrams for categories and functors in a different way, where lines are categories and boxes are functors, and parallel lines represent product categories. I don't have any theorem proving that this results in sound proofs, but it seems to work quite well.

My question is simply, what is the relationship between these things? What do monoidal categories and 2-categories have in common that allows such similar notation to be used for both, and are there other cases, besides the ones mentioned here, where string diagrams can also be used?

Comment: Much like a monoid is a category with one object, a monoidal category is a 2-category with one object.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable statement, but at the same time doesn't seem immediately obvious from the definitions. Do you know somewhere where it's worked out in more detail?

Comment: What definitions are you using for each? With the definitions in terms of a unitor and an associator, it's fairly immediate. You just have to know that the 1-cells are objects of the monoidal category, composition is the monoidal product, and 2-cells are the morphisms. The coherence diagrams for 2-categories reduce the the coherence diagrams for monoidal categories.

Comment: I found it worked out in these expository notes by Tai-Danae Bradley https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05923. We have to go to bigategories (which I'm not intimately familiar with) rather than 2-categories, because, I guess, 2-categories would correspond to strict monoidal categories. So I guess that answers my question.

Comment: Or rather, it partially answers my question, because I don't know any resource that really works out string diagrams as the notation for bicategories. If that existed it would be great, because then we could see how it specialises. Probably there's nothing nontrivial there, but a lot of this is folklore, hence hard to access.

Comment: [String Diagrams for Double Categories and Equipments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02762.pdf) describes a string diagram notation for double categories, which generalises that for 2-categories. [Shadows and traces in bicategories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1306.pdf) describes in passing the extension of string diagrams for monoidal categories to that for bicategories, with some examples.

Comment: The string diagram notation for bicategories is identical to the notation for 2-categories. Mac Lane's coherence theorem implies that every bicategory is appropriately equivalent to a 2-category, so anything you can prove with string diagrams (ignoring the associators and unitors) is valid in a bicategory. Indeed, this is the only reason string diagrams work for monoidal categories-notice that nobody ever indicates the unitors or associators explicitly. This is because we are implicitly mapping into our monoidal category from a *strict* monoidal category of string diagrams!